# Is it necessary to publish the results of the model on the training data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, cross-validation

For my thesis I am doing a quantitative research where I use the logistic regression. To improve the validity of my findings, I am cross-validating the logistic regression with a holdout sample.

The question that I have: do I need to publish the results of the model on the training data or is it enough to focus on the performance on the testing sample? I was wondering, because for the hypotheses-testing I only consider the results from the testing sample as relevant.

Comment: It sounds like you might have only a single held-out sample for testing. If so, then you're not really doing "cross validation" as the term is usually applied. [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20First%20Printing.pdf) is a good reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result on training set will be over-fitting the dataset. Your model is only learning to imitate the training set and the variance of your error will be pretty high. It is suggested to show testing result as a common metric.